# BERT's mask_token_id in relation to attention_mask

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to use BERTforMaskedLM to get probabilities of specific tokens in the text.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForMaskedLM

text = "George came home late last night"
spans = [(0,6), (27,33)]

model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokeniser = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

tokens = tokeniser(text, return_offsets_mapping=True)
input_ids = tokens["input_ids"]
attention_mask = tokens["attention_mask"]
```

And then for each span in the spans list I mask the tokens I want to predict. I change their attention_mask index to 0 and the input_id index to tokeniser.mask_token_id.

```
attention_mask[idx] = 0
input_ids[idx] = tokeniser.mask_token_id
```

My question is, if the attention mask stays as original is with all 1s to give the model more context, does that mean that the input_ids also need to be modified? Or are they not related in that sense?

Answer (score 0):

When `attention_mask` == 1  indicates that attention is paid to the token. Forcing it to zero effectively makes the token invisible. It has nothing to do with masking.

You should not replace tokens directly, since some words can be translated into several tokens, and masking half the word is useless. It is better to replace the words with tokenizer specific "mask" word. For `bert-base-uncased` it is `[MASK]`. Then tokenizer will take care of the translation. See HF [example](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertForMaskedLM.forward.example).

Also, masking several consecutive words will have negative impact the prediction quality.